# Android setOnClickListener errors

Tags: android, button

In the following code segment when built I keep breaking when adding the OnClickListener to the button.

```
package xxx.xxx.xxx;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.ListView;

public class TeaActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Button AddItem = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    AddItem.setOnClickListener(AddButtonHandler);
    }
    View.OnClickListener AddButtonHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
              // it was the first button

      }
    };
```

When debugging the code will break on the setOnClickListener() call. Not sure why

Comment: You shouldn't call `findViewById` before `setContentView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change it to this

```
AddItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener {
   public void onClick(View v) {
     TODO
   }
});
```

Comment: But then how would I get the AddButtonHandler to fire?

Comment: Thanks so much... For some reason earlier I couldn't get that to work. Thanks again

Comment: Sorry but this is not the correct answer you have to move your findViewById() after setContentView Or you will get always a NullPointer Exception

Comment: As stated above, although this is correct code this will not solve the problem in the originally stated code.  As I pointed out in my answer below and as pointed out before me in a comment on the original post, you cannot call findViewById before setContentView has been called otherwise it will return null.

Answer (score 3):

As aneal says you cannot call findViewById before the setContentView, the reason for this is that the xml layout has not been loaded yet and so findViewById will return null.  You probably then encounter a null pointer exception due to calling setOnClickListener on a null object.